What show/movie has a killer that cocoons its victims in webbing then turns out to be an alien. 80s/90s
This is either an episode of a show(like outer limits) or an actual movie. This would have been on tv in the 90's. I remember it taking place around something like a pueblo village. Something is killing the people, and even at one point kills a horse. Each of them, including the horse, is cocooned in a web of some kind. The last thing I remember is that it turned out to be an Alien of some sort in the end.
I watched a lot of late night b-movies, tnt monster vision, movies on USA network etc. back in the 90's. It is in COLOR.
Pretty certain this was in English. 
Of the horror variety. Seemed pretty scary as a kid at least... 

I wish whoever gave this question a negative would explain why, I've seen far more vague questions....

Not Cocoon, is it? Alieans leaving cocoons behind... http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0088933/?ref_=nv_sr_1

No it's not Cocoon. These people(and at least one horse) are killed and put into a webbing of some sort.

the title made me think of a weird description of IT

Definitely not IT.

Scary movie with an alien cocooning its victims reminds me of Xtro - http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0086610/ and http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0100975/?ref_=ttmi_tt and http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0115006/?ref_=ttmi_tt. However, I only saw the third installment, and I'm not sure about a poeblo village (and horse).

Have you looked at Kingdom of the Spiders?

It's not Kingdom of the Spiders or Xtro. I just watched Xtro to be sure.

It reminds me of the X-Files. Sure it's not this one? http://x-files.wikia.com/wiki/Darkness_Falls

There is a film called "meet the applegates" that has people wrapped in cocoons. They are giant preying mantises from Brazil that disguise themselves as people to try and take over the world or something I think. Believe stockard channing is in it
